# Вибрация в Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть в Unity3D такой вызов выбрации

```
Hanheld.Vibrate();
```

При его использовании 1 раз вибрирует телефон. 
На оффсайте всё без особых пояснений 
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handheld.Vibrate.html

Вопрос - проигрывать вибрацию более долгое или короткое время? Какие вообще возможности есть у этого метода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Встроенными средствами Юнити- никак. Вопрос решается плагинами. Простой и бесплатный в ассет стор = Vibration for Android

В нем много методов,мне пригодился метод для длительности вибрации.

```
Vibration(long millis)
```

Данный плагин бесплатен, но не лишен своих недостатков, в частности у меня вылетало на некоторых устройствах при смене ориентации экрана.

Можно обратиться к встроенному плагину Unity с помощью вспомогательных классов
https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html => Использование Java-плагинов со вспомогательными классами.

В данном случае код для вибрации будет выглядеть следующим образом.

```
public static class VibratorWrapper
{

static AndroidJavaObject vibrator = null;

static VibratorWrapper()
{

var unityPlayerClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
var unityPlayerActivity = unityPlayerClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
vibrator = unityPlayerActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getSystemService", "vibrator");

}
public static void Vibrate(long time)
{
if (HasVibrator()) vibrator.Call("vibrate", time);
}}
```

Теперь запускаем из любого класса

```
VibratorWrapper.Vibrate(2000L);
```

И вибрируем 2 секунды.
Примечание -  в папку Assets/Plugins/Android необходимо поместить файл манифеста с включенным правом на вибрацию. Например, так(файл рабочий).

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.unity3d.player"
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"/>

<application
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Встроенными методами никак, но это решается довольно просто написанием довольно простого плагина.
Как создавать плагины:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Plugins.html

создание соответствующих методов для айфона и андроида:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966467/are-there-apis-for-custom-vibrations-in-ios

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950338/how-to-make-an-android-device-vibrate

PS: А аттач целого ассета/библиотеки только для одного метода -- плохая идея.